# Button color changes only at the end of for loop

Tags: android

I am having 13 buttons and need to change the color of the button one by one.In below code "copyview" has button id and  "TextToSpeech"calls the TextToSpeech method. My problem is I am making to speak charter by character in tamil. But the button color changes only when for loop ends. The color of buttons are not changing one by one, at a stretch at the end of for loop all button colors changes to white. But  no problem with audio it play perfect. What I am suppose to do to make the color of button to get changed  one by one..

```
     for(int i=0;i<Uirkeys.length;i++){
        try {           
            TeaxtToSpeach(map.get(Uirkeys[i]));
            copyView.get(i).setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
            Thread.sleep(700);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: it will change immediately if you get rid of  Thread.sleep(700);

Comment: I need to wait for the audio to get complted and after that need to change the btn color.

Comment: I need to make for loop wait for each 700 ms for each increment how can I do that

Comment: NEVER use `Thread.sleep(...)` EVER. In particular you will cause problem locking up the UI when it's used. Instead of waiting for a set time, you should be using `TextToSpeech.OnUtteranceCompletedListener` or `UtteranceProgressListener` if you target API 18 or greater. The callback of the listener is called after the TTS system has finished  'speaking' and you can use it to change the button colour.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run it in the UI thread because you are running a UI change
this is an example

```
Activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            TeaxtToSpeach(map.get(Uirkeys[i]));
            copyView.get(i).setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        }
});
```